# How to skip a maven build step without modifying the pom itself?

Tags: maven

We have a maven based Java EE project controlled by the customer. For internal reasons, we cannot execute one of the build steps, but the rest works fine and produces the jar we want.

Since editing the pom file would require taking care when committing to customer's SVN and copying the pom file would require taking care to sync changes comming from there, we are looking for a way to skip this specific step in the build section during the maven call itself, so to say `mvn clean install but-leave-out-this-build-plugin-step`, is there any?

---

Edit:

The plugin in question is the rpm-maven-plugin, which prevents the build from running on Windows. We found information how to make it work which won't really fit in our current setup. And since we cannot modify the customer's pom, I was looking for a way to trigger the skipping externally. But maybe there are other ways to just ignore/skip/fake this step?

Comment: What exactly is this specific step you want to exclude?

Comment: @AleksandrM: It's the rpm-maven-plugin, specifically the rpm:attached-rpm goal

Comment: Without modifying the POM, you can't do that. Your best bet would be to introduce a specific profile that would contain the `rpm-maven-plugin` invocation, but that implies modifying the POM.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends on what plugin you want to skip. Many plugins have ability to be skipped via system property (-Dblabla).
For deploy plugin it is -Dmaven.deploy.skip=true, for surefire -DskipTests=true.
Read plugin documentation, maybe you can find skip property

---

The rpm plugin hase a property `disabled`, unfortunately it is not accessible by a property. So, if setting this property in the customer's pom (or asking for editing it) with a default value of false is an option, this may be the solution.

Comment: Ok, since you led me to the right spot, I'll edit your answer and credit it to you - thx